# Can someone explain exactly how the for loop in this code works?

Tags: c, loops

This code is supposed to display the fibonacci sequence for how ever many terms the user selects. The code works as intended, **I just want someone to explain how the for loop for this code block actually works.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main(void)
{
    int i, fibTerm, oneBack = 0, twoBack = 1, fibNum;
    double ratio;

    printf("How many fibonacci terms would you like to calculate?\n");
    scanf("%d", &fibTerm);

    for (i = 1; i <= fibTerm; i++)
    {   
        fibNum = oneBack + twoBack;
        twoBack = oneBack;
        oneBack = fibNum;
        printf("f(%d) = %d. The ratio is %lf\n", i, fibNum,);

    }
}
```

Comment: It "walks" up the sequence with fibNum being F(n) oneBack being the F(n-1), and twoBack being F(n-2). After each number, the oneBack becomes twoBack, then fibNum becomes oneBack and a new fibNum is computed.

Comment: The easiest way to see this is to make chart with all the variable names along the top. next execute each step of the program and write any changed values under the column for the variable that has changed. Then you will see the results that Scott describes in the previous comment.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? It's just assigning and adding variables, nothing at all complicated.

Comment: If you understand what Fibonacci numbers are, it should be clear how it works.

Comment: Barmar I do not understand which is why I am asking the question.

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour. You provide 3 format specifiers to `printf` but only 2 parameters. Do you really get the expected output? What to you expect? And: Don't you get some warning from your compiler about unused variable ?`ratio` and missing variable?

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci Sequence is the series of numbers: `[0, 1, ... ]` where the next number is found by adding up the two numbers before it.

```
0+1=1
1+1=2
2+1=3
3+2=5
5+3=8
...
```

Variables are initialised as:`oneBack = 0` and `twoBack = 1`.
So each time through the loop:

```
fibNum = oneBack + twoBack; // = 0+1=1
twoBack = oneBack;          // = 0
oneBack = fibNum;           // = 1

fibNum = oneBack + twoBack; // = 1+0=1
twoBack = oneBack;          // = 1
oneBack = fibNum;           // = 1

fibNum = oneBack + twoBack; // = 1+1=2
twoBack = oneBack;          // = 1
oneBack = fibNum;           // = 2

fibNum = oneBack + twoBack; // = 2+1=3
twoBack = oneBack;          // = 2
oneBack = fibNum;           // = 3

fibNum = oneBack + twoBack; // = 3+2=5
twoBack = oneBack;          // = 3
oneBack = fibNum;           // = 5

fibNum = oneBack + twoBack; // = 5+3=8
twoBack = oneBack;          // = 5
oneBack = fibNum;           // = 8

fibNum = oneBack + twoBack; // = 8+5=13
twoBack = oneBack;          // = 5
oneBack = fibNum;           // = 13

...
```

`i` is the loop counter, to stop calculating when the ith term calculated is the `fibTerm`th.

Your code has an extraneous format specifier and comma, so it shouldn't compile.
`printf("f(%d) = %d. The ratio is %lf\n", i, fibNum,);`
You probably meant:

```
ratio = oneBack / fibNum;
printf("f(%d) = %d. The ratio is %lf\n", i, fibNum, ratio);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and yes that is there because I deleted some variables from the original code before transferring here to make it less confusing. But I guess I forgot to fully fix it.